# p4 sync issue: Unable to sync all files after changing mapping and deleting folder

Tags: perforce

I wanted to change the path of mapping in perforce client

For ex:

```
//depot/a/... /home/user/xyz/...
```

to

```
//depot/a/... /home/user/p4/xyz/...
```

After changing the path using `p4 client`, I have deleted folder `xyz` using `rm -rf`.

Then ran `p4 sync` but I think some files are not getting synced to new path `p4/xyz/`.

Comment: Why do you think some files are not getting sync'd? What sync command did you run, and what output did it print? If you can identify a specific file that isn't being sync'd, try running 'p4 have' to display where Perforce thinks you already have that file, and what version it believes you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **force** (-f) flag. See [documentation](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r05.2/doc/manuals/cmdref/sync.html).

There should also be a checkbox in the GUI, if you're using the visual client.

Comment: using command line.I don't think `-f` is helping.It's just refreshing.

Comment: Uh... if `-f` doesn't work, then the files don't exist in your repo? :) You'll need to provide more information than "some files are not getting synced"...

Comment: @Scotty- `-f` is correct.I did little change and it worked for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The server thinks that the workspace/client already has the #head revision of these files and does not need to sync them again.

You can try using `-f` option to force a refresh however that is taking a hammer to problem that just needs a pair of pliers.

I would try a `p4 sync -k //depot/a/...#none` to update the server 'have' list. Type `[p4 help sync][1]` for more information about the command.

Comment: Doing things elegantly always feels nice :D

Comment: If you like elegance, try git.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here and none of the solution worked. It turns out that file I was trying to sync was `p4 opened`. Once I reverted that back using `p4 revert` it synced back.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works for me.

```
p4 sync -f //depot/a/...
```

What I did is,synced the whole base directory,directory which contains all my files and folders.

`-f` is necessary because it will actually copy, which doesn't happen in normal `sync` situation(try doing `ls` on file for confirmation).

In case of a single file `rm -rf` situation you can do

```
p4 sync -f path/to/file
```